# undefined parameter in map() method

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I'm trying to understand array functions but all the code examples are confusing for one particular reason. For example, in the code below the x is not defined. What is the role of x and how does this return the array elements multiplied by two?

```
const array1 = [1, 4, 9, 16];

// pass a function to map
const map1 = array1.map(x => x * 2);

console.log(map1);
// expected output: Array [2, 8, 18, 32]
```

Comment: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) `arr.map(function callback( currentValue[, index[, array]])`

Comment: You left me the same

Comment: It is a function. The map calls the function with arguments. The documentation link talks about it in detail. Does it make more sense without the [fat arrow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)?   `arr.map( function (valueOfIndex, theIndex) { return valueOfIndex * 2 })`

Comment: map is a function that accept a function as argument. And `x=>x*2` is a lambda function that accept argument `x` and return `x*2`

Comment: the `x` is a function argument, so, it actually is defined for each iteration of map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have to spend some time understanding the language structure, the MDN documentation explains it well enough, The "map" function goes through/iterate each and every element in the "array1", where "x" serves as the current value/parameter for each loop, runs the expression with the current value and create a new array containing the computation done by each element being iterated.

I hope this explanation helps you understand it better, you can read further for more depth.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Answer (score 0):

[The MDN arrow function documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) covers this quite well.

`x => x * 2`

is shorthand for

```
function(x) {
    return x * 2;
}
```

Comment: I understand it is an arrow function. What I don't understand is where x came from because it's not defined anywhere.

Comment: here's another example i've seen online                                                                             var numbers = [65, 44, 12, 4];
var newarray = numbers.map(myFunction)

function myFunction(num) {
  return num * 10;
}

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = newarray;;                here the num is not defined either

Comment: It is defined as an argument. The map method passes the value to the function. It does not care what you call the argument.

Comment: `x => x * 2` is the same as `y => y * 2` is the same as `apples => applies * 2`

Answer (score 0):

You can read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) about `map` function.

It's taking function `foo` as argument and returns a new array after applying this function `foo` on every value in the array.

You can define functions in javascript as follow:

```
function foo(x) {
    return x*2;
}
```

or like this:

```
(x) => x*2;
```

The second form is an arrow function which has no name and can be defined inline.
It's getting argument `x` and returns `x*2`, just like function `foo`.

So `map` applies this function `foo` on every value of `array1`, so `x` in this case is value in `array1`.

Instead of writing this:

```
array1.map(x=>x*2);
```

You can write:

```
for(let i in array1) {
    array1[i] = foo(array[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`map` has a callback and it has three arguments. It does not matter what you name those arguments. The name of the arguments does not matter, you can name them foo a, b, cat, world, dude, etc.

When it loops over your array it takes whatever is in the index of the array and passes it to the function you provide. So if the first index of your array contains a number, it passes that number.

The second parameter is the index. The third parameter is the array it is looping.

```js
function doubleIt(x, index) {
  console.log(x, index)
  return x * 2
}
function tripeleIt(foo, index) { 
  console.log(foo, index)
  return foo * 3
}

var myArray = [1,2,3,4]

console.log(myArray.map(doubleIt))
console.log(myArray.map(tripeleIt))
```

Under the hood map looks like this (I named it xmap so it can run)

```js
Array.prototype.xmap = function (callback) {
  var theArray = this;
  var theResult = [];
  for (var index = 0; index < theArray.length; index++) {
    var indexValue = theArray[index];
    theResult[index] = callback(indexValue, index, theArray)
    //                      ^^^^^^^^^^ Where the first argument comes from                
  }
  return theResult;
}

var x = [1,2,3,4].xmap(x => x * 2)
console.log(x)
```